# Issue with Rxjs Observable in Angular 2 Latest

Tags: angular, rxjs, electron, observable

Hello i am trying update **signinText** `var` through the Observable call back. Iam receiving data in **console.log** but data is not changing in HTML. `this.fadeInputs()` callback is successful but data is not updating.

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {RequestUpload} from "../_Class/RequestUpload";
let request = require('request');

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    fade: boolean = false;
    signinText: string;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fadeInputs(true);
        this.call('login/get','POST',{mobile:9000000000,password:1234},[],false).subscribe(
            (value) => {
                console.log(value);
                this.fadeInputs(false);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                this.fadeInputs(false);
            },
            () => {
                this.fadeInputs(false);
            }
        );
    }

    fadeInputs(fadeType: boolean) {
        console.log("Working");
        this.fade = fadeType;
        this.signinText = !this.fade ? "Sign In" : "Please Wait!";
    }


    private call(url: string, type: string, postData: {}, files: string[], cache: boolean) {
        url = "http://192.168.40.136:146/" + url;

        var RequestConfig = {};
        RequestConfig['method'] = type;
        RequestConfig['url'] = url;
        RequestConfig['auth'] = {
            'user': "admin",
            'pass': "1234"
        };

        let CheckFileSize = 0;
        if (type == "POST") {
            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (postData == null) {
                    postData = {};
                }
                let i = 0;
                for (let file of files) {
                    postData['file_' + i] = fs.createReadStream(file);
                    i++;
                    CheckFileSize += fs.statSync(file).size;
                }
            }
            if (postData != null) {
                RequestConfig['formData'] = postData;
            }
        }
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            let r = request(RequestConfig, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                    observer.error({
                        error: error,
                        response: response,
                    });
                } else {
                    observer.next({response: response, body: body});
                    observer.complete()
                }
            }).on('drain', () => {
                observer.next({upload: new RequestUpload(r.req.connection.bytesWritten, CheckFileSize)});
            });
        })
    }

}
```

and i tried below code and its working. don't know whats wrong in "request" module

**Below Code is Working fine.**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fadeInputs(true);
    Observable.create((observer) => {
        setInterval(() => {
            observer.next('check')
        }, 1000)
    }).subscribe(
        (value) => {
            this.fadeInputs(!this.fade);
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `request()` is doing exactly but it might leave Angulars zone. Try to inject `private zone:NgZone` and wrap the callback code (if(error || ...`) with `this.zone.run(/* callback code here */);`

Comment: Ohh Thank you it works,...  @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1):

request module is running on other zone. so need to wrap it in to angular zone.

USE:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
// Your Code Here
})
```

Thanks to @GünterZöchbauer

```
constructor(private userService: UserService, private zone: NgZone) {

}
```

---

```
return Observable.create((observer) => {
    let r = request(RequestConfig, (error, response, body) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                observer.error({
                    error: error,
                    response: response,
                });
            } else {
                observer.next({response: response, body: body});
                observer.complete()
            }
        })
    }).on('drain', () => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            observer.next({upload: new RequestUpload(r.req.connection.bytesWritten, CheckFileSize)});
        })
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `request()` somehow leaves Angulars zone (this happens when async API is used that is not patched by zone.js).

With `zone.run(...)` the execution can be brought back into Angulars zone and Angular will know again when to run change detection.

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) { }

call(...) {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        let r = request(RequestConfig, (error, response, body) => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
                observer.error({
                    error: error,
                    response: response,
                });
            } else {
                observer.next({response: response, body: body});
                observer.complete()
            }
          });
        }).on('drain', () => {
            observer.next({upload: new RequestUpload(r.req.connection.bytesWritten, CheckFileSize)});
        });
    })
}
```